# Plotting 1 dimensional data

Tags: graphing-functions, data-analysis

I have measured the diameter and circumference of various (ca. 50) circular objects and would like to plot the ratio, i.e., circumference:diameter in order to show that those values are close to pi.

How can I do that? I am not asking for technical help but rather on the best way to present the data to laymen.

One difficulty might be that several numbers are identical and I do want to distinguish this, i.e. if I have three times the value 3.2 that should be graphically distinct from just once the same value.

One way to present this would be in a bar diagram, but I want something more direct, without (randomly chosen) intervals.

The normal way, of plotting circumference vs diameter and getting pi from the slope is unfortunately no option, because the audience does not know about the concept of "slope".

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the circumference on the Y axis against the diameter on the X axis you should see an approximately linear relationship between the two.

Since $C=\pi D$, the line of best fit for the data should have a slope of approximately $
\pi$. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I would do. The problem is that the audience would have difficulty understanding what is going on because they don't know much about "slope". I was more thinking along the line of plotting it one dimensional as a number line and to somehow scale the data points in case they are doubled or tripled. Or perhaps use colour?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a scatter plot? Then it would give a clear line (or use a line of best fit) with slope $\pi$ (approximately).

Comment: This is what I would do, but I need it simpler/more direct  because the concept of slope is not known to the audience.

Comment: Make an excel table, with the columns as the data, and an extra column as the ratio. Then plot those on a scatter plot and say y=3.1?

Comment: That sounds like the easiest, thanks. So ratio vs number from 1 to 50...?

Comment: I assume? Or take average of first n trials and also talk about how more trials lead to more accuracy. What's the level of your audience lol, introducing pi for the first time?